# Magento 2 Paytrace Echeck Payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, paytrace

I have create module for Caputure payment by Bank Cheque, I have created following mode and extends `\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod` class.

In checkout page i have created two field `Account Number` and `Routing Number`. But in payment method model file when i am not able to get `Account Number` and `Routing Number` in `capture function`. I have check other CC Payment method they are able to get CC NUmber, Exp Date etc in model file.

Anyone have idea how can i get checkout field `Account Number` and `Routing Number` detail that added by user in Model file ?

**Model File**

```
<?php

namespace NameSpace\Module\Model;

use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class Paytraceecheck extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{

    const METHOD_CODE = 'popayment';

    protected $_code = self::METHOD_CODE;

    protected $_isGateway = true;

    protected $_canCapture = true;

    protected $_canCapturePartial = true;

    protected $_canRefund = true;

    protected $_minOrderTotal = 0;

    protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('USD');

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param Logger $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface $moduleList
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface $moduleList,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        \NameSpace\Module\Helper\Data $popaymentHelperData,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encription,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $extensionFactory,
            $customAttributeFactory,
            $paymentData,
            $scopeConfig,
            $logger,
            $resource,
            $resourceCollection,
            $data
        );
        $this->_moduleList = $moduleList;
        $this->_localeDate = $localeDate;
        $this->popaymentHelperData = $popaymentHelperData;
        $this->_encryption = $encription;
        $this->_transactionFactory = $transactionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Authorise Payment.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment
     * @param float $amount
     * @return $this
     */
    public function authorize(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount) {
        try {
            $token = $this->getAuthorizeToken();
            if(isset($token['access_token'])) {
                $saledata = $this->createTransaction($token['access_token'], $payment, $amount, 'authorization');
                if(isset($saledata["success"]) && $saledata["success"] && $saledata['response_code']==101 && $saledata['transaction_id']){
                    $payment->setTransactionId($saledata['transaction_id'])->setIsTransactionClosed(0);
                    $payment->setTransactionAdditionalInfo(
                        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction::RAW_DETAILS, $saledata
                    );
                    return $this;
                } else {
                    $this->debugData([$saledata]);
                    if (isset($saledata["errors"])){
                        $errormessage = $this->getErrorMessageFromArray($saledata["errors"]);
                        throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__($errormessage)); 
                    } else if(isset($saledata["approval_message"])){
                        throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__("Payment Error: ".trim($saledata["approval_message"]))); 
                    } else {
                        throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__("Payment error.")); 
                    }
                }
            } else {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__('Token not found.')); 
            }
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__('Payment error.'));
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Capture Payment.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment
     * @param float $amount
     * @return $this
     */
    public function capture(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
    {
        try{
            $token = $this->getAuthorizeToken();
            if(isset($token['access_token'])) {
                if($payment->getLastTransId()) {
                    $transaction = $this->_transactionFactory->create();
                    $transaction->load($payment->getLastTransId(),"txn_id");
                    if($transaction->getTransactionId() && $transaction->getTxnType() == 'authorization') {
                        $saledata = $this->createTransaction($token['access_token'], $payment, $amount, 'capture');
                        if(isset($saledata["success"]) && $saledata["success"] && $saledata['response_code'] == 112 && $saledata['transaction_id']){
                            $payment->setTransactionAdditionalInfo(
                                \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction::RAW_DETAILS, $saledata
                            );
                            return $this;
                        } else {
                            $this->debugData([$saledata]);
                            if (isset($saledata["errors"])) {
                                $errormessage = $this->getErrorMessageFromArray($saledata["errors"]);
                                throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__($errormessage)); 
                            } else if(isset($saledata["approval_message"])) {
                                throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__("Payment Error: ".trim($saledata["approval_message"]))); 
                            } else {
                                throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__("Payment error.")); 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $saledata = $this->createTransaction($token['access_token'], $payment, $amount, 'sale');
                    if(isset($saledata["success"]) && $saledata["success"] && $saledata['response_code'] == 101 && $saledata['transaction_id']){
                        $payment->setTransactionId($saledata['transaction_id'])->setIsTransactionClosed(0);
                        $payment->setTransactionAdditionalInfo(
                            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction::RAW_DETAILS, $saledata
                        );
                        return $this;
                    } else {
                        $this->debugData([$saledata]);
                        if (isset($saledata["errors"])) {
                            $errormessage = $this->getErrorMessageFromArray($saledata["errors"]);
                            throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__($errormessage)); 
                        } else if(isset($saledata["approval_message"])) {
                            throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__("Payment Error: ".trim($saledata["approval_message"]))); 
                        } else {
                            throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__("Payment error.")); 
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__('Token not found.')); 
            }
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__('Payment error.'));
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
    }

    public function refund(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
    {
        try{
            $token = $this->getAuthorizeToken();

            if(isset($token['access_token'])) {
                //$this->debugData([$token['access_token']]);
                $saledata = $this->createRefundTransaction($token['access_token'], $payment, $amount);
                $this->debugData([$saledata]);
                if(isset($saledata["success"]) && $saledata["success"] && $saledata['response_code']==101 && $saledata['transaction_id']){
                    $payment->setTransactionId($saledata['transaction_id'])->setIsTransactionClosed(0);
                    $payment->setTransactionAdditionalInfo(
                        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction::RAW_DETAILS, $saledata
                    );
                    return $this;
                } else {
                    if (isset($saledata["errors"])){
                        $voidsaledata = $this->createVoidRefundTransaction($token['access_token'], $payment, $amount);
                        $this->debugData([$voidsaledata]);
                        if(isset($voidsaledata["success"]) && $voidsaledata["success"] && $voidsaledata['response_code']==109 && $voidsaledata['transaction_id']){
                            $payment->setTransactionId($voidsaledata['transaction_id'])->setIsTransactionClosed(0);
                            $payment->setTransactionAdditionalInfo(
                                \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction::RAW_DETAILS, $voidsaledata
                            );
                            return $this;
                        }else{
                            $this->debugData([$voidsaledata]);
                            $errormessage = $this->getErrorMessageFromArray($voidsaledata["errors"]);
                            throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__($errormessage));
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__('Error in refund transaction.')); 
                    }
                }

            } else {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__('Token not found.')); 
            }
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__('Error in refund transaction.'));
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
    }

    public function getErrorMessageFromArray($temp){
        if(is_array($temp))
        {
            $extractval = reset($temp);
            if(is_array($extractval)){
                return $this->getErrorMessageFromArray($extractval);    
            } else {
                return $extractval;
            }
        } else {
            return $temp;
        }
    }

    public function createRefundTransaction($token, $payment, $amount){
        if($payment->getLastTransId()){
            $integrator_id = $this->getConfigData('integrator_id');
            $apiurl = $this->getConfigData('apiurl').'v1/transactions/refund/xxxxxx';
            $headers = array(
              'Authorization: Bearer '.$token,
              'Content-Type: application/json',
              'Cache-Control: no-cache'
           );
             $param = array(
                'amount'=> $amount,
                "transaction_id"=>$payment->getLastTransId(),
                "integrator_id"=>$integrator_id
            );

            $requestString = json_encode($param,true);
            //$this->debugData([$requestString]);
            //$response = $this->_helperData->makeApiRequest($apiurl, $requestString, $headers);
            return '';
        }
    }

    public function createVoidRefundTransaction($token, $payment, $amount){
        if($payment->getLastTransId()){
            $integrator_id = $this->getConfigData('integrator_id');
            $apiurl = $this->getConfigData('apiurl').'v1/xxxx/xxxx';
            $headers = array(
              'Authorization: Bearer '.$token,
              'Content-Type: application/json',
              'Cache-Control: no-cache'
           );
             $param = array(
                'amount'=> $amount,
                "transaction_id"=>$payment->getLastTransId(),
                "integrator_id"=>$integrator_id
            );

            $requestString = json_encode($param,true);
            //$this->debugData([$requestString]);
            //$response = $this->_helperData->makeApiRequest($apiurl, $requestString, $headers);
            return '';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get authorize token from Paytrace
     *
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function getAuthorizeToken() {
       $apiurl = $this->getConfigData('apiurl').'xxxx/xxxx';
       $username = $this->getConfigData('username');
       $password = $this->_encryption->decrypt($this->getConfigData('password'));
       $param = [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password
        ];
        $requestString = http_build_query($param);
        $response = $this->popaymentHelperData->makeApiRequest($apiurl, $requestString);
        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * [createTransaction description]
     *
     * @param  [type] $token   [description]
     * @param  [type] $payment [description]
     * @param  [type] $amount  [description]
     * @param  string $type    [description]
     * @return [type]          [description]
     */
    public function createTransaction($token, $payment, $amount, $type = 'sale') {
        $order = $payment->getOrder();
        $billing = $order->getBillingAddress();
        $integrator_id = $this->getConfigData('integrator_id');
        $headers = [
            'Authorization: Bearer '.$token,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Cache-Control: no-cache'
        ];
        $street = $billing->getStreet();
        if(is_array($billing->getStreet())) {
            $street = implode(" ",$billing->getStreet());
        }

        if($type == 'capture') {
            $apiurl = $this->getConfigData('apiurl').'v1/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx';
            $param = [
                "transaction_id" => $payment->getLastTransId(),
                "integrator_id" => $integrator_id
            ];
        } else {
            $apiurl = $this->getConfigData('apiurl').'v1/xxxxx/'.$type.'/xxxxx';
            $param = [
                "amount" => $amount,
                "check" => [
                    "account_number" => $payment->getEcheckAccountNo(),
                    "routing_number" => $payment->getEcheckRoutingNo()
                ],
                "email" => $order->getCustomerEmail(),
                "customer_reference_id" => $order->getIncrementId(),
                "integrator_id" => $integrator_id,
                "billing_address" => [
                    "name" => $billing->getName(),
                    "street_address" => $street,
                    "city" => $billing->getCity(),
                    "state" => $billing->getRegion(),
                    "zip" => $billing->getPostcode()
                ]
            ];
        }

        $requestString = json_encode($param, true);
        $response = $this->popaymentHelperData->makeApiRequest($apiurl, $requestString, $headers);
        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Check whether there are CC types set in configuration
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface|null $quote
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAvailable(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigData('integrator_id')) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Availability for currency
     *
     * @param string $currencyCode
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canUseForCurrency($currencyCode)
    {
        if (!in_array($currencyCode, $this->_supportedCurrencyCodes)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Assign data to info model instance
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject|mixed $data
     * @return $this
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function assignData(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $data)
    {
        $additionalData = $data->getData(PaymentInterface::KEY_ADDITIONAL_DATA);
        if (!is_object($additionalData)) {
            $additionalData = new DataObject($additionalData ?: []);
        }

        /** @var DataObject $info */
        $info = $this->getInfoInstance();
        $info->addData(
            [
                'echeck_account_name' => $additionalData->getEcheckAccountName(),
                'echeck_bank_name'    => $additionalData->getEcheckBankName(),
                'echeck_routing_no'   => $additionalData->getEcheckRoutingNo(),
                'echeck_account_no'   => $additionalData->getEcheckAccountNo()
            ]
        );
        return $this;
    }
}
```